# How can I write a Ruby one-liner to read a small AR table into a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model called `Category` that contains about a thousand records. It changes extremely infrequently. I want to avoid millions of database hits by caching it, which is no big deal.

But I found that I didn't know how to do it in one line. I can do it in two:

```
category_hash = {}
Category.each { |c| category_hash[c.id] => category }
```

I know how to return a 2D array from the block. But is there a way to create and return a hash from such a block?

Comment: Probably, but if it's at the price of readability would it be worth it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Rails there's [Enumerable#index_by](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-index_by):

```
category_hash = Category.all.index_by(&:id)
```

Without Rails I'd use:

```
Hash[Category.all.map{ |c| [c.id, c] }]
```

[`Hash::[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) creates a Hash from both, flat and nested Arrays:

```
Hash["a", 100, "b", 200]             #=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200}
Hash[ [ ["a", 100], ["b", 200] ] ]   #=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Category.all.reduce(Hash.new) { |h, c| h[c.id] = c; h }
```

Comment: It barfs on the fat arrow. and when I change it to an =, I get only one row.

Comment: @AKWF try `Category.all.reduce(Hash.new(nil)) { |h, c| h[c.id] = c ;h}` .

Answer (score 2):

You can do this way:

```
Category.each_with_object({}) { |c,category_hash| category_hash[c.id] = category }
```